# How to merge 5 queries in single query in procedure to decrease the execution time

Tags: stored-procedures

I want your help in my project.
I have one table called employee_details. It has four columns:

```
user_id VARCHAR2(255)) 
user_name(VARCHAR2(255))
nickname(VARCHAR2(255))
created_on(date)
```

Now I have written 5 separate queries in procedure to fetch the data for users who registered/created_on during period `sysdate-1`, `sysdate-30`, `sysdate-60`, `sysdate-90` and on `sysdate` but I want to fetch this data in just single query, so that execution time of procedure can be decreased. Please help me, and please let me know if more details are required.

So far I have written following queries:

```
1.   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT mth.user_id)
            FROM employee_details mth                 
           WHERE mth.created_on < TO_DATE (todate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
             AND mth.created_on >= TO_DATE (fromdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
                                      - 90;
2.   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT mth.user_id)
            FROM employee_details mth                 
           WHERE mth.created_on < TO_DATE (todate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
             AND mth.created_on >= TO_DATE (fromdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
                                      - 60;
3.   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT mth.user_id)
            FROM employee_details mth                 
           WHERE mth.created_on < TO_DATE (todate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
             AND mth.created_on >= TO_DATE (fromdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
                                      - 30;
4.   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT mth.user_id)
            FROM employee_details mth                 
           WHERE mth.created_on < TO_DATE (todate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
             AND mth.created_on >= TO_DATE (fromdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
                                      - 1;
5.   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT mth.user_id)
            FROM employee_details mth                 
           WHERE mth.created_on < TO_DATE (todate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')+1
             AND mth.created_on >= TO_DATE (fromdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR');
```

where `fromdate` and `todate` are going to replaced by sysdate from procedure call.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit to add your query as it currently stands? If you can show that you are attempting to solve the problem, people can assist in a more focused manner and this question won't get closed as "too broad".

Comment: Thanks - this makes it clearer and shows that you are actively working on this, not just seeking someone to write the code for you! Another question - are you looking for a single count of distinct users across all 5 subqueries, or are you looking for a count per subquery?

Comment: Hi Chris, I want seperate count per subquery but there should not be 5 subqueries separately like above in procedure. I just want something like as 90 is the largest difference it will be fetched first and then for 60 it should fetch from above 90 and should not fetch from table.

Comment: Hello Chris , please help me

Answer (score 0):

Get no of days count (based on what period you want i.e. 1, 30, 60 or 90 etc..) as a parameter to your procedure and try something like below:

**This example is to get last 3 days created records (Today Dt. 1st April, 2015)**

```
SELECT * FROM emp_temp WHERE created_on >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY);
```

[image]

Hope this may help you...

Thanks,

**~Chandan**